# TypeScript overloads with a type in quotes

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, typescript

Given this TypeScript interface:

```
interface JQuery {
    ...
    data(): any;
    data(obj: { [key: string]: any; }): JQuery;
    data(key: string): any;
    data(key: string, value: any): JQuery;
    ...
    data(key: any): any;
    data(key: "kendoMobileActionSheet") : kendo.mobile.ui.ActionSheet;
    data(key: "kendoMobileBackButton") : kendo.mobile.ui.BackButton;
}
```

And this code:

```
var actionSheet: kendo.mobile.ui.ActionSheet = $("#item").data("kendoMobileActionSheet");
```

I get an error stating that it cannot convert type JQuery to type ActionSheet. How can I get the type of actionSheet to be kendo.mobile.ui.ActionSheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine for me in the [Typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/):

```
interface ActionSheet {
    value: string;
}

interface JQuery {
    data(): any;
    data(key: any): any;
    data(key: "ActionSheet") : ActionSheet;
}

var jq: JQuery;
var numVar: number = jq.data(1);
var asVar = jq.data("ActionSheet");
var sVar = asVar.value;
```

Probably the thing can be in the typescript transpiler version or some other environment.

Comment: Ok So it is correct TypeScript and should work as advertised. It is probably an issue with my includes like having the definition of data(key: any)  included with jquery.d.ts and the other data(key: "ActionSheet") included with kendo.mobile.d.ts